# when to use div#idname or #idname for css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

To style the code:

```
   <div id="top-header">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="http://example.com/>logo link</a>

        </div>
</div>
```

When does one use `div#logo{}`
and when does one use `#logo{}`?

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique, so prefixing "div" is redundant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`div#logo` will only apply to elements with the id of `logo` that are divs, whereas just `#logo` will apply to any element with the id of `logo`. However, given that you shouldn't have elements with the same id on the same page, this particular occasion should not make any difference.

It's much more useful when styling by class instead of id, for example:

```
<div class="top-header">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="http://example.com/>logo link</a>

    </div>
    <span class="logo">Hello</span>
</div>
```

Here `div.logo{}` will not apply the style to the span.

Comment: While you mustn't have elements with the same ID on the same page as it'll fail validation and could cause mysterious bugs, it IS possible to have (let's say) div#logo on one page and h1#logo on another. It doesn't seem good practice but would be valid.

Comment: @yochannah Of course. I was implying on the same page - I'll edit my answer to clarify that.

Comment: +1 for my dumbness, misjudged `class` as `id`

Comment: @VenomVendor No problem. Easy enough to miss I suppose.

Answer (score 4):

The only time `div#logo` is useful is if you want to select one element, which has the id `logo` and is a `<div>`, or select no elements if such a `<div>` doesn't exist. This use case implies that you don't know until runtime whether `#logo` will be the id of a `<div>` or some other HTML element like a `<span>`.

If you just want to select the element with the id `#logo`, then just use `#logo`.

Answer (score 2):

ID are meant to be unique meaning in a Web page with 1000,000 Divs containining 1000,000 IDs, each Div  should have a Specific ID, however, these can have the same class.

Example: Consider this as a class room in a school with 1000 students. Each students has his/her own specific student ID but they all share the same class.

so, if the students will be Divs, a student with ID number (#) 567, will be graded like this in css:

Supposing this:

```
     <student id="1" class="Grade_03">...</student> // as in <div id="1" class="Grade_03"></div>

    <student id="2" class="Grade_01">...</student>
    <student id="3" class="Grade_02">...</student>
    <student id="n" class="Grade_03">...</student>

    Student#567{
    Math:90%;
    English:80%;
    }

//Or:

  #567{
    Math:90%;
    English:80%;
    }
```

but if you wanna address all the students in that class, let's say Grade_03:

```
Student.Grade_03{
TeacherName:"Mr_Smith";
}
```

Saying `Student#567` or `#567` both will direct to the same student, provided you do NOT have duplicate student IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Since an `id` is unique, `#logo{ ... }` will be enough.

When using classes, you can be more flexible, for example:

CSS:

```
.class1 {
    color: red;
}

span.class1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1 class="class1">heading</h1>
<a class="class1">link</a>
<span class="class1">span</span>
```

In the above example, the heading and link text will be red. The span however, will be blue.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as "I *only* want to select an element with this id if it happens to be a div.".
In 99% of the cases using the `id` selector is enough, but if the element is added dynamically and you know what id it will have but not what kind of element it will be, you have to do it this way.

Answer (score -4):

IDs are always unique.

There is no use of adding `element` selector in front of an ID.

Here is the reason why you should avoid using same IDs with a page. http://jsfiddle.net/jDxS8/1/ When you try to add styles on the fly, you can't.

**EDIT :** I misjudged [Mansfield](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18389465/1008278%20is%20technically%20wrong)'s comment `class="logo"` as `id` sorry for that.

Comment: It is possible to add elements with the same id, even if it isn't a good idea: http://jsfiddle.net/Mansfield/jDxS8/

Comment: incorrect, it adds specificity and thus has a use http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Also - there can be h1#logo on one page and div#logo on another page but hey can share the same CSS.

Comment: @yochannah Here is what Cris say about IDs at the bottom of the article http://css-tricks.com/website-critique-epicawesome-co/

Comment: @Mansfield I agree it's possible, It's is not a good idea. Try applying the same style using Javascript.

Comment: It can be necessary, as you code more HTML,CSS and Javascript, you'll come across this one day.

Comment: @ErickBest @jaa-c in that case I would pefer `.` class

Comment: @Mansfield Here is a quick update http://jsfiddle.net/jDxS8/1/

Comment: Yah, classes are the Answer, but not in all cases... >> See my answer above

Comment: @ErickBest you have said Student#567 is same as #567 and is correct , so why do you want to waste the bytes adding `Student`

Comment: What if it happens that you have `Student#15` in the `Student's` List and `Teacher#15` in the `Teacher's` list?, when you say: #15 to whom will the code be directed?... That is why at times in some rare cases, you may end up in such a quandary if not careful. So, explicitly calling Student#15 will be the wise course toTake.

Comment: @ErickBest are you aware that IDs should be unique?? Your code will work but it's technically 100% wrong to use same IDs. If the page follows W3C standards then `Student#15` & `Teacher#15` should be `Student.15` & `Teacher.15`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to prove. I know that the OP is not suggesting the best way to do things, and I know how to use javascript. I'm just saying that for his purposes those CSS rules will do the same thing, which is completely true. And no, my answer is not "technically wrong", at least not in any way you're describing.

Comment: You'll learn more as time goes by... for now, Just Relax!

Comment: @ErickBest Plz prove, that am wrong. Wake Up..

Comment: Your comment stated that  >> Mansfield is wrong.... Which is technically incorrect. If you re-read his comment, you'll Notice how astray you went, when you misjudged his comment.

Comment: I did notice that, am feeling dumb now. but still you are wrong probably not correct. :D

Comment: This is SOverflow, a place where all come. Be it Props  or rookies.. Not a bad idea to contribute, but check and re-check before you make a move. One more thing. The usage of the Element#idname is also for flexibility, you are telling the engine to concentrate on a particular element tag and get the ID from there. Should you say: #15 in a page with Tables, Divs, Spans and tagN, the Search goes blindly to all elements, but saying div#15, the search will stick to divs and this may prove to be quicker...(Proven by Professionals)

Comment: @ErickBest It's completely unacceptable to have the same `id` more than once on a page. No professional web developer would ever let that occur, but Jaa-c's comment is a perfectly valid reason to downvote this answer. There is a use of specifying the element type. It filters to only that element type, so you may select `0` elements when you would've selected `1` before.